# Is using VR still possible while having both ocular drones launched?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

Assuming a character has Cyber Eyes with one Ocular Drone each. In addition, they have a Datajack serving as DNI.

Can they still use Virtual Reality (especially the Rigging features) while having both Eyes launched? If not, would that be possible if the DNI was provided by a Rigger Console instead of a Datajack? (Rules as written if possible)

Comment: So basically your question boils down to "Is it possible to control 2 drones in VR"?

Comment: No, it is more of: "If you don’t have eyes, can you still go into VR using a DNI?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

On page 266, under Rigger Command Console (RCC)

> A rigger command console, or RCC, is like a deck for controlling drones (or other vehicles and devices). It’s about the size of a briefcase. It can act like a commlink and has all the features of a commlink in addition to the cool drone stuff.

You would, of course, need to connect to the RCC either via trodes or your datajack. Or get an implanted RCC and just ignore all of that!

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer: yes

> How Can <strike>Mirrors</strike> **VR** Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real
>
> *A slightly modified Jaden Smith quote*

The eye is the input (capture). the brain process the data (see).

Cyber eyes are trideo cameras that replace your eyes (different input) but it's your brain that still sees. They connect to the brain in a similar way regular eyes are connected to the brain. The ocular drone however simply allows the cyber eye to leave the body and broadcast their video feed to your brain.

Like it's name suggest, a DNI (direct neural interface) connects your brain to devices. It's a **direct** connection, so you don't need another input (eyes) to interact with the device.

When you are in VR, your brain process the Matrix **directly**. Your physical eyes will just shut down like sleeping but because your ocular drones are, as their name suggest, drones. You can control them in VR like any drones.